# Is this vulnerable to SQL injection?

Tags: sql-injection

We are using a third party product which references a stored procedure in MSSQL. This stored proc looks something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[example]
 @a nvarchar(255)
 AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @strSQL nvarchar(3000)
  SET @strSQL = 'SELECT * FROM test WHERE x = ''1'''

  IF IsNull(@a, '') <> ''
    SET @strSQL = @strSQL + ' AND a = ''' + @a + ''''
  EXEC(@strSQL)
END
```

This stored proc doesn't actually output its results to the website but I'm still sure that it is vulnerable to SQL injection. I can input t' + 'est and get the same result as I would from inputing test.

We obviously need to get them to change this but I need to demonstrate that it is an issue first. How can I do something like insert a row in to a table by passing SQL in as @a? If I do

```
'; INSERT INTO blah VALUES('test')
```

Then I get:

```
Incorrect syntax near ';'.
```

Comment: It almost looks like SQL is automatically preventing the semicolon from being input? This is onl SQL2012

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes, it's vulnerable, but by chance you've injected the wrong text, producing a syntax error:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE x = "1" AND a =; INSERT INTO blah VALUES('test')
                                        ^--your syntax error
```

If your injection text had been:

```
a; INSERT blah blah blah
^---
```

then you'd have ended up with two valid queries and `test` in your blah table.

Comment: Hmm but it looks like it should end up as SELECT * FROM test WHERE x = "1" AND a =''; INSERT INTO blah VALUES('test')

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set your @ to have an secape character and thus create mutiple Execs ulimately leading to execcmd format C: or other - google SQL injection attacks

However:

Create proc db.eg @a nvarchar(255)

AS
BEGIN

Update Mytable SET Mycol = @a WHERE Condition etc..

END

IS not open to SQL injection as the string goes directly to the table column, it is nt exec'd